# RabbitMQ Can't receive message

Tags: java, rabbitmq

In the example i am using the same class than this tutorial : 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

I have 2 classes : 
Send.java

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class Send {

    public static final String QUEUE_NAME="hello";



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection=null;
        Channel channel =null;
        try {
            connection = factory.newConnection();
            channel = connection.createChannel();
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME,false,false,false,null);
            String message = "Hello word toto";
            channel.basicPublish("",QUEUE_NAME,null,message.getBytes());
            System.out.println(" [ x ] Sent '"+message+"'");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                channel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the receiv class :

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class Receiv{
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection=null;
        Channel channel=null;
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        try {
            connection = factory.newConnection();
            channel = connection.createChannel();
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
            System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
            Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel){
                @Override
                public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                        throws IOException {
                    String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
                }
            };
            channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                channel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i get i compile like the example but i don't see the **received message**

Thank you.

Comment: did you send messages to the queue?

Comment: I am using the channel direcly but why ?

Comment: you will receive messages when you send them first, so if you did not send any messages to the queue (the queue is empty) then you will not receive any messages

Comment: Thank you but in the tutorial (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) I don't think he use the queue.

Comment: simply , what i mean is, you need to start the send class first, then start the other one

Comment: But when i start the send class first and start the other one i not receive the message can you test please maybe i didin't do a good compilation thanks

Comment: Could you please take a look at RabbitMQ log files and see if you see the two connections logged?